# Unity Deactivating Keyboard Input Interpolation

Tags: unity, input, keyboard

I'm working on a game in Unity, and it is a little jarring to use with keyboard controls. I'm using the built in Input Manager, where I have a set of axes mapped to the left and right keys. When the player is using the keyboard instead of a joystick, I'd like it to simply be -1 when hitting left, 1 when hitting right, and 0 otherwise, but this isn't the case. I've found that for the first few frames of the button being held, Unity automatically builds up to the value-- for example, if I'm holding right, the value wouldn't go straight from 0 to 1, but rather from 0, to 0.25, to 0.5 and so on, continuously up to 1. Can I deactivate this? If so, how?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably you've already configured the gravity, sensitivity, and snap parameters in the [Input Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html)? Can you show us the values you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in method [Input.GetAxisRaw](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html)

From the docs:

> Returns the value of the virtual axis identified by axisName with no
>   smoothing filtering applied.
>
> The value will be in the range -1...1 for keyboard and joystick input.
>   Since input is not smoothed, keyboard input will always be either -1,
>   0 or 1. This is useful if you want to do all smoothing of keyboard
>   input processing yourself.